# On Dynamic Allocation of Matrices

Tags: c, arrays, matrix

Usually people dynamically allocates matrices as

```
double **A;

int N,i,j;

N=10;

A = (double **)malloc(N*sizeof(double *));

   for(i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
    A[i]= (double *)malloc(N*sizeof(double ));
    }
```

Based on some discussion in the class, I have learned that this is not very efficient for large matrices. This creates an array of pointers to array allocated in different places in the memory, changing rows in this kind of allocation is more costly. So the instructor proposed using this form of allocation:

```
double *A;

int N;

N=10;

A = (double *)malloc(N*N*sizeof(double));
```

Where you access i,j element of the matrix by looking at A[N*i + j]. I would like to allocate my matrices like this but I would like to keep my old notation which is A[i][j]. Thus one way that comes to my mind is to do the bad allocation first, that is create double** A as described in the first part. Then set

```
 A = (double **)malloc(N*sizeof(double *));
 temp = (double *)malloc(N*N*sizeof(double ));

 for(i=0; i<N; i++)
    {   
        A[i]=&temp1[i*N+j];    
    }
```

This code seems to work but I know only the basics of memory allocation, so I would like to ask if there is anything problematic with this kind of allocation, is it any different than just keeping with the array temp1. Thanks

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9656380/how-to-dynamically-allocate-a-matrix-in-c?rq=1

Comment: @Quest That is not a duplicate.

Comment: Yes this thread is not about where the adresses of each elements are assigned to. But neverthless I have realized there is a stupid mistake in my code, I dont know how it ran but it is not true.

Comment: The problem is that `j` is not initialized so you set random addresses...but if `j` is 0 or you omit the `j` term from the initialization, then you should be OK.  Some compilers have problems with pointers to arrays — that may be why your Tiny C compiler isn't handling the proposed solution very well.

Answer (score 2):

This is easy to do, just declare `A` to be a pointer to a line array:

```
double (*A)[N] = malloc(N*sizeof(*A));

for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
        A[i][j] = /*whatever*/;
    }
}
```

If the notation I used is unclear to you, read it from the inside out: `A` is defined to be a pointer (`(*A)`) to an array of `N` elements (`(*A)[N]`), which happen to be of type `double` (`double (*A)[N]`). This pointer is initialized with the return value of `malloc()` (it might be irritating that the `=` does not follow the identifier `A`, but this is the same syntax as in `char myName[] = "Foo, Bar B.";`). It might be a bit more clear if you split the line and/or use a `typedef`:

```
double (*A)[N];
A = malloc(N*sizeof(*A));
```

or

```
typedef double MatrixLine[N];
MatrixLine* A = malloc(N*sizeof(*A));
```

In C (not in C++) the `typedef` works fine even if `N` is a dynamically computed value, I could even use `typedef double MatrixLine[random()];`, not that it would make much sense... C is extremely flexible in this respect!

It might also be interesting to know how to cast a pointer to the type of A, here is the correct cast included:

```
double (*A)[N];
A = (double (*)[N])malloc(N*sizeof(*A));
```

Note that the cast is precisely the same syntax as the declaration of `A`, only with the identifier omitted.

---

Note 1:
Since C99 you are allowed to declare loop variables right in the `for()` statement. Use this, it makes your code much more readable.

Note 2:
In C, it is not required to cast the return value of `malloc()`, and it does not add to your code to write it anyway. However, C++ does require the cast, so if you want to use your code in a C++ project, go ahead and cast.

Comment: Here the allocation is of N is not dynamic is it? When I try to run this it gives the error constant expression expected, I guess it means the N? Also the notation

      double (*A)[N] = malloc(N*sizeof(*A));

is a bit confusing to me. What kind of object does it create? Is it double** or something else? Thanks

Comment: You are not using a C++ compiler to compile this C code, are you? Because C++ is more restrictive concerning array sizes than C. In C, it is perfectly fine to have `N` be a dynamically calculated value; C++, however, requires all array sizes to be constants. As to the notation, I'll try to add some explanation about this to my answer. Just hang on a sec.

Comment: I am using tinyc c compiler

Comment: I have never used tinyc (I didn't even know about its existence until a few minutes ago), so I don't know anything about how well it implements the various language standards. Variable length arrays are a part of the language at least since C99, and, accordingly, the code that I gave compiles fine with `gcc -std=c99`. So it seems to me as if tinyc does not completely/correctly implement the language standard.

Comment: I don't know why but I simply run

   `int N;
   N=100; 
   double (*A)[N];
   A = malloc(N*sizeof(*A));`

to see how it works but it says constant expression expected. I will try gcc and return back thanks.

Comment: Just copied your code and compiled with `gcc -std=c99 bar.c`, and it works fine without any compiler or runtime errors. Seems to be the compiler :-(